# How to read from files with Files.lines(...).forEach(...)?

Tags: java, file, foreach, filereader, line-by-line

I'm currently trying to read lines from a text only file that I have. I found on another stackoverflow([Reading a plain text file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file)) that you can use Files.lines(..).forEach(..) 
However I can't actually figure out how to use the for each function to read line by line text, Anyone know where to look for that or how to do so?

Comment: That method is already reading each line of the file, you can store the line in a `String` variable and do something else with it...

Comment: Uhm, you should read about Java 8 and lambdas; specifically here, about `Consumer` and the notion of single abstract method

Answer (score 38):

Sample content of test.txt

```
Hello
Stack
Over
Flow
com
```

Code to read from this text file using `lines()` and `forEach()` methods.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class FileLambda {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Path path = Paths.of("/root/test.txt");
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
            lines.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          // do something or re-throw...
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You may use method reference: `System.out::println`, still it would be translated to the same bytecode.

Comment: And one more point: you should not store `Stream` as variable because it may confuse some readers to use it twice or more times, which is prohibited. Instead, you may save it to `List` with `readAllLines`, then use method `stream()` on this list.

Comment: Use try-with-resources for the stream to ensure it gets auto-closed:
`try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {`

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg Would you store the `Stream` as a variable for files too big for `readAllLines`?

Comment: @Noumenon why should I? I can use `Files.lines` result immediately.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg I got this confused with a try-with-resources answer on a different page. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: I'm getting "java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException" even though executing file and txt file both are in the same folder and I'm putting address as filename.

Answer (score 11):

Avoid returning a list with:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path); //WARN
```

Be aware that the entire file is read when `Files::readAllLines` is called, with the resulting String array storing all of the contents of the file in memory at once. 
Therefore, if the file is significantly large, you may encounter an `OutOfMemoryError` trying to load all of it into memory.

Use stream instead: Use `Files.lines(Path)` method that returns a `Stream<String>` object and does not suffer from this same issue. 
The contents of the file are read and processed lazily, which means that only a small portion of the file is stored in memory at any given time.

```
Files.lines(path).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I have a doubt here. Will the Files.lines() return stream of each line or will it return a stream out of the whole file? Please clarify.

Comment: "Read all lines from a file as a Stream."  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-

Answer (score 6):

With **Java 8**, if file exists in a `classpath`:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("input.txt")
                    .toURI())).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Files.lines(Path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) expects a `Path` argument and returns a `Stream<String>`. [`Stream#forEach(Consumer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) expects a `Consumer` argument. So invoke the method, passing it a [`Consumer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html). That object will have to be implemented to do what you want for each line.

This is Java 8, so you can use lambda expressions or method references to provide a `Consumer` argument.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a sample , you can use the Stream to filter/

```
public class ReadFileLines {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("C:/SelfStudy/Input.txt"));
//      System.out.println(lines.filter(str -> str.contains("SELECT")).count());

//Stream gets closed once you have run the count method.
        System.out.println(lines.parallel().filter(str -> str.contains("Delete")).count());
    }
}
```

Sample input.txt.

```
SELECT Every thing
Delete Every thing
Delete Every thing
Delete Every thing
Delete Every thing
Delete Every thing
Delete Every thing
```