# How do I make this bufferedReader loop keep going?

Tags: java, loops, boolean

I have a BufferedReader loop that checks if the next lines != null, If the line has text on it, the reader will read the line, now I successfully made it do this,
it reads the line and then It wont read the next because it already went thought the if loop, what would i do to make it keep reading lines until there are no more lines to read? I could use a while loop but Im kinda confused as to where to put it.

```
int numberOfLines = 0;
String[] textData = new String[numberOfLines];

if (red.readLine() != null) {
    numberOfLines++;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
        textData[i] = red.readLine();
        //System.out.println(textData[i]);
        textArea.append("\n");  //Break line after every read line
        textArea.append(textData[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: don't use an if block, use a while loop

Comment: Use a **loop** and not an `if`. Or, even better, use [`Files.lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-).

Comment: Wow thanks I feel like an idiot.

Comment: Giving me an  `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Well, `numberOfLines = 0` therefore `textData.size == 0`. What did you expect?

Comment: What would I set it to?

Comment: As I said, use `Files.lines`. Stop learning ancient and outdated techniques...

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
   int numberOfLines = 0;
   String[] textData = new String[numberOfLines];
```

So your array has zero size.
Doing this later:

```
numberOfLines++;
```

does not grow the array.  In fact, you can't grow an array.
You want a data structure (like an ArrayList) that can grow.

See also [How to read from files with Files.lines(...).forEach(...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276407/how-to-read-from-files-with-files-lines-foreach) for an alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while` loop. And because Java arrays are fixed length, you'll need to copy the elements into your newly expanded array. Also, *please* use `System.lineSeparator()` (not every system uses `\n`). Something like,

```
String[] textData = new String[0];
String line;
int i = 0;
while ((line = red.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] dest = new String[textData.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(textData, 0, dest, 0, textData.length);
    dest[i++] = line;
    textData = dest;
    textArea.append(System.lineSeparator() + line);
}
```

Alternatively, you could read into a `Collection` (like `ArrayList`). Something like,

```
List<String> textData = new ArrayList<>();
String line;
while ((line = red.readLine()) != null) {
    textData.add(line);
    textArea.append(System.lineSeparator() + line);
}
```