# Use cases for BaseStream.onClose

Tags: java, java-stream

BaseStream provides the method [`onClose`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#onClose-java.lang.Runnable-) which takes a Runnable. Is this a method relevant for application programmers? Is it primarily intended be used when using a stream that needs to be closed, such as `Files.lines()`, as in this question: [How to read from files with Files.lines(...).forEach(...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276407/how-to-read-from-files-with-files-lines-foreach)? What use cases are there for this method (apart from logging).

Comment: Closing resources is exactly the intention of the `onClose` action; in all other cases, the application is unlikely to close the Stream at all. Therefore it is crucial to document when a Stream holds resources that need closing. For an application programmer, it will be relevant, when (s)he implements a resource based stream, e.g. [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32232173/2711488) implements a custom JDBC `ResultSet` based Stream…

Comment: @Holger: Thank you for the example. Actually, when inspecting the source code of `Files.lines()`, I noticed it also uses `onClose` to close the BufferedReader it opens to read from the file when the stream is closed.

Comment: I assumed that you know the `Files.lines` example, as you referred to it. I wanted to provide an example of something not covered by the JRE, as that’s exactly the place, where an application programmer has to deal with it.

Comment: @Holger: The `Files.lines` example was originally only serving as an example of an stream which needs to be closed after use, and I guessed `onClose()`  might be somehow be useful in such a context. It was a coincidence, and I realized only after your comment, that `onClose` is actually used in the implementation of `Files.lines`