# How to read a config file with only value in java?

Tags: java

i already read related post about reading a.config. The strategy is to use property, and method getproperty().

But what if i only have values there? how can i extract all value out?
for example:

```
server1 127.0.0.1 50000
server2 127.0.0.1 50001
server3 127.0.0.1 50002
server4 127.0.0.1 50003
server5 127.0.0.1 50004
server6 127.0.0.1 50005
server7 127.0.0.1 50006
server8 127.0.0.1 50007
```

I wanted to read the whole file as a stringbuilder and parse it, but i am not sure if there is any other better way to process this config file.

Comment: How about reading the file line by line using `BufferedReader`? A config file is nothing more than a simple file. If you are using a framework, then the framework might provide you some specialized classes for reading the file. Otherwise use simple `BufferedReader` or one of Apache commons utils.

Comment: What Prashant says and then use String.split ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677411/iterating-over-the-content-of-a-text-file-line-by-line-is-there-a-best-practic

Answer (score 1):

You can also use org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class SomeClass 
{

    public static void main(String argp[]) throws Exception
    {
        List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(new File("d:/temp/config.txt")) ;

        List<Config> configs= new ArrayList<Config>() ;
        for(String line:lines)
        {
            line = line.trim();

            if(line.equals(""))
                    continue ;

            Config config= new Config() ;
            String[] values= line.split(" ");
            config.server = values[0] ;
            config.ip = values[1] ;
            config.ip = values[2] ;         
            configs.add(config) ;
        }

        for(Config config:configs)
            System.out.println(config) ;
    }

    public static class Config
    {
        public String server = "" ;
        public String ip = "" ;
        public String port = "" ;

        @Override
        public String toString() 
        {
            return "config [server=" + server + ", ip=" + ip + ", port=" + port
                    + "]";
        }               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you plan is to read this file and make a complex object with a serverid ipaddress and port?

If so there are hundreds of examples online for reading a file

```
    String fileName = "c://lines.txt";

    //read file into stream, try-with-resources
    String[] valueSplit;
    List<SomeObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {

        valueSplit = stream.split(" ");
        list.add(new SomeObject(valueSplit[0],valueSplit[1], valueSplit[2]);


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I would have ideally created a `<<LineMapper>>` that returns an instance of a class that represents a configuration line and then used it for mapping each line with `SomeObject`. But this works too. :D

Comment: @Prashant definitely agreed but from the context of the question, I assumed he may not be using Spring

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `.properties` file type.
In this you can declare the field and later extract them with the .getProperty() method.

With this you don't have to worry about parsing the content.

**Example**

File content of `config.properties`

```
server1=127.0.0.1:50000
server2=127.0.0.1:50001
server3=127.0.0.1:50002
server4=127.0.0.1:50003
server5=127.0.0.1:50004
server6=127.0.0.1:50005
server7=127.0.0.1:50006
server8=127.0.0.1:50007
```

**java code** to retrieve

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties config = new Properties();
        try {
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("path/to/file"));
            config.load(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(config.getProperty("server1"));
        System.out.println(config.getProperty("server2"));
        System.out.println(config.getProperty("server3"));
        System.out.println(config.getProperty("server4"));
        System.out.println(config.getProperty("server5"));
        System.out.println(config.getProperty("server6"));
        System.out.println(config.getProperty("server7"));
        System.out.println(config.getProperty("server8"));

    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
127.0.0.1:50000
127.0.0.1:50001
127.0.0.1:50002
127.0.0.1:50003
127.0.0.1:50004
127.0.0.1:50005
127.0.0.1:50006
127.0.0.1:50007
```

Comment: The OP has specifically mentioned that the config file does not have key value pairs. Moreover, your approach requires the knowledge of the number of servers. When I look at a config file, as provided by OP, I get a feeling that the code in question, might not have any idea of the keys at all. `server1` only seems to be a simplified key. The actual server name could be quite complex. This approach might not be the most optimal solution.

Comment: In my approach server name can be complex but we'll still be able to fetch the value.