# What's the best way to split this text file?

Tags: java, data-structures, split

basically i have this java assignment in which I need to take the following text file:
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NqWtApSHovOfSXzVCeU_GPtsCo_m6ZtJ/view?usp=sharing

The legend for the text file is here:
E: did the elector result in promotion (1) or not (0)
T: time election was closed
U: user id (and screen name) of editor that is being considered
for promotion
N: user id (and screen name) of the nominator

### V: vote(1:support, 0:neutral, -1:oppose), user id, time, screen_name

And create the following two methods:

1. Given a user id, output the total number of times the user has voted to support or be neutral or oppose the candidate considered for promotion
   for all people the user has voted for collectively in all the elections.
2. Given a user id considered for promotion, output the user id and
   screen name of the nominator. For multiple nominations, you will
   output all nominators. If the user is not nominated ever, output
   an appropriate message.

I'm really lost on how I should go about splitting the text file into pieces to help me obtain the information needed to create the two methods. Any insight would really be great

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Being an assignment, the answer really depends on what you have done in the course that the assignment is supposed to reinforce/assess. Try starting with whatever seems reasonable to you and asking more specific questions if you get stuck :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to create different string reader loops that iterate over the text file line by line. Nobody here will do this for you because it´s to much work, and it´s your work!

Here´s a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677411/iterating-over-the-content-of-a-text-file-line-by-line-is-there-a-best-practic) about iterating-over-the-content-of-a-text

Answer (score 0):

You can use the str.split() method. You write the point in the text at which you would like to split in the brackets.
For example if you have the following;

`String str "Hello world";
     String [] arrayString = str.split (" ");// splits the string at the space
     for( String a:arrayString);
     System.out.println(a);`

Output:

Hello

World